# Replacing embedded HTML5 videos with links

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace WebM videos on any webpage with links.

So, I've written a simple code, but it doesn't work. And I don't know why.

```
(function(){
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
    var vidUrl = video[i].src;
    if (video[i].src.match(/\.webm$/i)) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vidUrl));
        a.setAttribute("href", vidUrl);
        video[i].parentNode.replaceChild(a, video[i]);
    }
}
})();
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kdqv3637/)

Does anyone have any advice please?

Comment: Purpose of `jquery` tag?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'src' attribute is set on the `source` element, not the `video` element in your jsfiddle example.  See my [edited jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/032hfu0r/) which will match `video` or child `source` elements:

```
    //var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    var video = document.querySelectorAll('video[src], video source[src]'),
        vidElement;

    for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
        vidElement = video[i];
        var vidUrl = vidElement.src;
console.log(vidUrl);        
        if (vidElement.src.match(/\.webm$/i)) {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(vidUrl));
            a.setAttribute("href", vidUrl);
            // make sure we replace video element instead of source
            if (/source/i.test(vidElement)) vidElement = vidElement.parentNode;

            vidElement.parentNode.replaceChild(a, vidElement);

        }
    }
```